# Bug in A_LoopFileFullPath? Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

This autoHotKey Script produce a crazy output:

- A_LoopFileFullPath= E:\fre\private\HtmlDevelop.stversions
- A_LoopFileFullPath=E:\fre\private\HtmlDevelop.stversions
- A_LoopFileName=.stversions
- A_LoopFileDir=E:\fre\private\HtmlDevelop
- A_ScriptDir = E:\fre\private\HtmlDevelop\AutoHotKey

but the fullpath of .stversions is 
- E:\fre\private\HtmlDevelop\AutoHotKey.stversions
and not 
- A_LoopFileDir=E:\fre\private\HtmlDevelop.stversions

sure its possible to fix that. but why that happens? is that a bug in autohotkey?

```
Loop, %A_ScriptDir%/*.*, 2 , 1
{
if(StrLen(A_LoopFileFullPath) < StrLen(A_ScriptDir))
{
; thats bullshit
continue
}
;~ ToolTip,A_LoopFileFullPath=%A_LoopFileFullPath%
MsgBox,,,A_LoopFileFullPath= %A_LoopFileFullPath% `n     A_LoopFileFullPath=%A_LoopFileFullPath% `n A_LoopFileName=%A_LoopFileName% `n A_LoopFileDir=%A_LoopFileDir% `n A_ScriptDir=%A_ScriptDir%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug, make sure you have the latest version from [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) and also try `A_LoopFileLongPath` instead of the `FullPath` built-in variable.

Comment: result was as expected (see below)

Comment: result now as expected with version 1.1.19.03 (see below). and modified script little (see below)

A_LoopFileFullPath= E:\fre\private\HtmlDevelop\.stversions 
     A_LoopFileFullPath=E:\fre\private\HtmlDevelop\.stversions 
 A_LoopFileName=.stversions 
 A_LoopFileDir=E:\fre\private\HtmlDevelop 
 A_ScriptDir=E:\fre\private\HtmlDevelop\AutoHotKey 
 1.1.19.03 = A_ahkVersion (line:9) 
 Tools: SciTE4AutoHotkey, SL5_AHK_Refactor_engine

https://gist.github.com/sl5net/6930f490dbef10efbb05